# Detect user returning to page on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way in JavaScript/JQuery to detect that a user has left the tab/web browser app and returned on Mobile?

On Desktop it's pretty simple with JQuery and 'mouseleave' type functions, but I can't figure out a solution for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the focus and blur event on your window?  This should work in all modern browsers including mobile ones.

```
var focused = true;

window.onfocus = function() {
    focused = true;
};
window.onblur = function() {
    focused = false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

What about comparing time and timeout (halted at leaving)?:

```
function isleaving(callback){
 function check(val){
 var time=new Date().getTime() / 1000;
 val=val||time;
 if(val==time){
 //All ok so keep checking
setTimeout(function(){check(time+1);},1000);
}else{
callback();
}
}
check();  
}
```